# Old questions appear in "active" question list

Tags: discussion, bug, support

I sometimes get questions in my "active" question list that obviously aren't active. From what I can see with my reputation level those questions haven't been edited, answered nor are there any new comments. In the question list they are tagged like they were only few minutes old, but when I open them, all date tags are outdated.

Why do they appear in my question list?

Latest examples (part of top 20 in my list):

- [Safely enabling voltage divider on a 12V battery](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/16722/38721)
- [help compiling code for flora project](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/21328/38721)
- [Sending servo position data from one Arduino to another](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/51302/38721)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with VE7JRO - the bot "Community" does this stuff. It is a bit annoying because you see a list of old questions for no obvious reason. Community is trying to either get an answer, or get someone to upvote an existing answer. Questions with no answers, or no answer with upvotes are considered by the bot to be open, and it is trying to jog us to do something about them.

The take-out for users in general is:

- Answer questions in an answer, not just a comment. See [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).
- Up-vote answers to indicate you agree with them (when appropriate) - don't just nod your head without reaching for your mouse.
- If you asked the question, "accept" the best answer. Don't just silently accept the help without feeding back into the system that the answer worked.
- If no answers seem to be particularly good, answer it yourself.
- If it's an old question (and the OP probably has forgotten about it by now) then vote to close it.

Comment: If it's a question that you know has been asked elsewhere and got an answer vote to close as dupe

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question "12V battery...", Gerben edited his answer, so the question became "active" again.

The second question was modified by "Community". Community is a automated process that goes through old questions with no accepted answers and makes them active so they show up on the Arduino SE "home page".

If you find an answer in one of these "reactivated" questions that solves the problem, please consider accepting it. This should stop Community from making it active again.

Keep in mind that it's OK to answer your own question and accept it as the solution.